# Query NoSQL Array que contenga uno o más valores

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

estoy adentrándome en el mundo del no sql y me ha surgido un problema. tengo una lista de objetos por ejemplo:

```
[ 
    {
      nombre: "manolito",
      idiomas: [ 123456, 654321 ]
    }, {
      nombre: "gafotas",
      idiomas: [ 654321 ]
    }, {
      nombre: "pepe",
      idiomas: [ 741258 ]
    } 
]
```

donde idiomas es una lista de objectid. La pregunta és: teniendo una lista de posibles valores, pongamos: [741258,123456]. ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta preguntando si la lista contiene una o más coincidencias?. En este caso concreto debería devolverme manolito y pepe.

Es un poco difícil de explicar, así que si queda alguna duda preguntad y os responderé con la mayor brevedad posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso usas el operador `$in` ([ver la documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array))

```
objetos.find({
    "idiomas":{
         "$in":[741258,123456]
     }
});
```

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias